# Is it possible to select internal InnoDB columns?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have read that InnoDB uses a few fields internally for all rows, such as the hidden columns DB_TRX_ID and DB_ROW_ID.  Is there any easy way to see these values, such as within a select statement?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using ???

Comment: This question is related to version >= 5.1.56 for my environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no metadata available for that info. The two fields you are asking for

- `DB_TRX_ID`
- `DB_ROW_ID`

are only visible from a textual viewpoint in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`

You can learn more about it from the [**MySQL 5.1 Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-monitors.html)

MySQL 5.5+ offers some metadata for live transactions

```
mysql> use information_schema
Database changed
mysql> select version(),database();
+-----------+--------------------+
| version() | database()         |
+-----------+--------------------+
| 5.5.9-log | information_schema |
+-----------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show tables like 'INNODB%';
+----------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_information_schema (INNODB%) |
+----------------------------------------+
| INNODB_CMP_RESET                       |
| INNODB_TRX                             |
| INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET                    |
| INNODB_LOCK_WAITS                      |
| INNODB_CMPMEM                          |
| INNODB_CMP                             |
| INNODB_LOCKS                           |
+----------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

MySQL 5.6 offers even more:

```
mysql> use information_schema
Database changed
mysql> select version(),database();
+------------+--------------------+
| version()  | database()         |
+------------+--------------------+
| 5.6.10-log | information_schema |
+------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show tables like 'INNODB%';
+----------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_information_schema (INNODB%) |
+----------------------------------------+
| INNODB_LOCKS                           |
| INNODB_TRX                             |
| INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES                   |
| INNODB_LOCK_WAITS                      |
| INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS                  |
| INNODB_CMP                             |
| INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED                |
| INNODB_CMP_RESET                       |
| INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX                   |
| INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET                    |
| INNODB_FT_DELETED                      |
| INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU                 |
| INNODB_FT_INSERTED                     |
| INNODB_CMPMEM                          |
| INNODB_SYS_INDEXES                     |
| INNODB_SYS_TABLES                      |
| INNODB_SYS_FIELDS                      |
| INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET             |
| INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE                     |
| INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD             |
| INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE                  |
| INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE                  |
| INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES                 |
| INNODB_METRICS                         |
| INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS                |
| INNODB_FT_CONFIG                       |
| INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS               |
| INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS                     |
| INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN                     |
+----------------------------------------+
29 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Keep in mind that these are living, breathing entities. Do no bother run a `COUNT(*)`. By the time you do, queries have disappeared and other queries have materialized.

Here is a sample:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.INNODB_TRX\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                    trx_id: 24E6E0FC5
                 trx_state: RUNNING
               trx_started: 2013-04-22 16:34:54
     trx_requested_lock_id: NULL
          trx_wait_started: NULL
                trx_weight: 0
       trx_mysql_thread_id: 20275587
                 trx_query: (SELECT
                                        GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS('','{\"type\":\"',report_stats.type,'\",\"date\":',report_stats.date,',\"leadID\":',report_stats.leadID,',\"vehID\":',report_stats.vehID,',\"contactID\":',report_stats.contactID,'}') SEPARATOR '::') customers,
                                        COUNT(*) total, CONCAT_WS('',sales.id,'^^',sales.first,' ',sales.last) sales
                                FROM
                                        D6195.report_stats
                                        LEFT JOIN D6195.report_stats self ON report_stats.leadID=self.leadID AND report_stats.vehID=self.vehID
JOIN D6195.leads ON report_stats.leadID=leads.id
LEFT JOIN icar.sales  ON sales.id=leads.salesID
                                WHERE
                                        report_stats.date BETWEEN 1364788800  AND 1367294400 AND
                                        report_stats.type IN ('Internet Lead') AND FROM_UNIXTIME(report_stats.date,'%k') BETWEEN 9 AND 18 AND self.type='First Response'  GROUP BY CONCAT_WS('',sales.id,'^^',sales.first,' ',sales.last) ASC WITH ROLLUP)
       trx_operation_state: NULL
         trx_tables_in_use: 4
         trx_tables_locked: 0
          trx_lock_structs: 0
     trx_lock_memory_bytes: 376
           trx_rows_locked: 0
         trx_rows_modified: 0
   trx_concurrency_tickets: 0
       trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
         trx_unique_checks: 1
    trx_foreign_key_checks: 1
trx_last_foreign_key_error: NULL
 trx_adaptive_hash_latched: 0
 trx_adaptive_hash_timeout: 6850
*************************** 2. row ***************************
                    trx_id: 24E6E0ECD
                 trx_state: RUNNING
               trx_started: 2013-04-22 16:34:54
     trx_requested_lock_id: NULL
          trx_wait_started: NULL
                trx_weight: 0
       trx_mysql_thread_id: 20275545
                 trx_query: SELECT * FROM
                        (
                        SELECT
                                actionQue.id  scheduled_action_id,
                                actionQue.date contact_due_date,
                                actions.description,
                                IF(actions.callscript = 0,null,actions.callscript) phone_script_id,
                                actions.priority,
                                leads.id customer_id,
                                CONCAT_WS('',leads.first,' ',leads.last)  customer_full_name,
                                IF((leads.dPhone IS NULL AND leads.ePhone IS NULL AND leads.fax IS NULL) OR leads.noCall='true',0,1) isContactableByPhone,
                                IF((leads.email IS NULL AND leads.email1 IS NULL) OR (leads.noBroadcast!='false' AND leads.noBroadcast IS NOT NULL),0,1) isContactableByEmail,
                                IF(leads.custSince=0,null,leads.custSince)  customer_creation_date,
                                vehicles.soldDate sold_date,
                                IF(leads.lastContact=0,null,leads.lastContact) customer_last_contact_date,
                                IF(leads.modDate!=0,leads.modDate,null) customer_modified_date,
                                CONCAT_WS(' ',vehicles.year,makes.name,models.name) vehicle_description,
                                sources.name ad_source_name,
                                CONCAT_WS(' ',sales.first,sales.last) employee_name,
                                actionQue.v
       trx_operation_state: starting index read
         trx_tables_in_use: 12
         trx_tables_locked: 0
          trx_lock_structs: 0
     trx_lock_memory_bytes: 376
           trx_rows_locked: 0
         trx_rows_modified: 0
   trx_concurrency_tickets: 0
       trx_isolation_level: REPEATABLE READ
         trx_unique_checks: 1
    trx_foreign_key_checks: 1
trx_last_foreign_key_error: NULL
 trx_adaptive_hash_latched: 1
 trx_adaptive_hash_timeout: 0
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

You could dump the queries to a text file, and follow up with `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`

That is all that MySQL currently exposes for InnoDB's internal metadata.

Here are all the table structures

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_LOCKS
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_LOCKS` (
  `lock_id` varchar(81) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lock_trx_id` varchar(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lock_mode` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lock_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lock_table` varchar(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lock_index` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lock_space` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lock_page` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lock_rec` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lock_data` varchar(8192) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_TRX
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_TRX` (
  `trx_id` varchar(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `trx_state` varchar(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `trx_started` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `trx_requested_lock_id` varchar(81) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trx_wait_started` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `trx_weight` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_mysql_thread_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_query` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trx_operation_state` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trx_tables_in_use` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_tables_locked` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_lock_structs` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_lock_memory_bytes` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_rows_locked` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_rows_modified` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_concurrency_tickets` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_isolation_level` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `trx_unique_checks` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_foreign_key_checks` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_last_foreign_key_error` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trx_adaptive_hash_latched` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_adaptive_hash_timeout` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_is_read_only` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trx_autocommit_non_locking` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES` (
  `SPACE` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PATH` varchar(4000) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_LOCK_WAITS
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_LOCK_WAITS` (
  `requesting_trx_id` varchar(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `requested_lock_id` varchar(81) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `blocking_trx_id` varchar(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `blocking_lock_id` varchar(81) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS` (
  `TABLE_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `STATS_INITIALIZED` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NUM_ROWS` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CLUST_INDEX_SIZE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OTHER_INDEX_SIZE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MODIFIED_COUNTER` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AUTOINC` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `REF_COUNT` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_CMP
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_CMP` (
  `page_size` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `compress_ops` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `compress_ops_ok` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `compress_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uncompress_ops` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uncompress_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED` (
  `DOC_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_CMP_RESET
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_CMP_RESET` (
  `page_size` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `compress_ops` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `compress_ops_ok` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `compress_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uncompress_ops` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uncompress_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX` (
  `database_name` varchar(192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `table_name` varchar(192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `index_name` varchar(192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `compress_ops` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `compress_ops_ok` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `compress_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uncompress_ops` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uncompress_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET` (
  `page_size` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `buffer_pool_instance` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pages_used` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pages_free` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `relocation_ops` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `relocation_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_FT_DELETED
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_FT_DELETED` (
  `DOC_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU` (
  `POOL_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LRU_POSITION` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SPACE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGE_NUMBER` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGE_TYPE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLUSH_TYPE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FIX_COUNT` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IS_HASHED` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NEWEST_MODIFICATION` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OLDEST_MODIFICATION` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ACCESS_TIME` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TABLE_NAME` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INDEX_NAME` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMBER_RECORDS` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DATA_SIZE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `COMPRESSED_SIZE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `COMPRESSED` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IO_FIX` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IS_OLD` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FREE_PAGE_CLOCK` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_FT_INSERTED
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_FT_INSERTED` (
  `DOC_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_CMPMEM
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_CMPMEM` (
  `page_size` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `buffer_pool_instance` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pages_used` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pages_free` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `relocation_ops` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `relocation_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_SYS_INDEXES
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_SYS_INDEXES` (
  `INDEX_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TYPE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `N_FIELDS` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGE_NO` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SPACE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_SYS_TABLES
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_SYS_TABLES` (
  `TABLE_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` varchar(655) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `FLAG` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `N_COLS` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SPACE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FILE_FORMAT` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROW_FORMAT` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZIP_PAGE_SIZE` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_SYS_FIELDS
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_SYS_FIELDS` (
  `INDEX_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `POS` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET` (
  `database_name` varchar(192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `table_name` varchar(192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `index_name` varchar(192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `compress_ops` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `compress_ops_ok` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `compress_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uncompress_ops` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uncompress_time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE` (
  `POOL_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `BLOCK_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SPACE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGE_NUMBER` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGE_TYPE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLUSH_TYPE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FIX_COUNT` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IS_HASHED` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NEWEST_MODIFICATION` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OLDEST_MODIFICATION` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ACCESS_TIME` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TABLE_NAME` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INDEX_NAME` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMBER_RECORDS` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DATA_SIZE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `COMPRESSED_SIZE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGE_STATE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IO_FIX` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IS_OLD` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FREE_PAGE_CLOCK` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD` (
  `value` varchar(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE` (
  `WORD` varchar(253) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `FIRST_DOC_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LAST_DOC_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DOC_COUNT` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DOC_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `POSITION` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE` (
  `WORD` varchar(253) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `FIRST_DOC_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LAST_DOC_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DOC_COUNT` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DOC_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `POSITION` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES` (
  `SPACE` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` varchar(655) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `FLAG` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FILE_FORMAT` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROW_FORMAT` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PAGE_SIZE` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ZIP_PAGE_SIZE` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_METRICS
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_METRICS` (
  `NAME` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SUBSYSTEM` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COUNT` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MAX_COUNT` bigint(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MIN_COUNT` bigint(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVG_COUNT` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNT_RESET` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MAX_COUNT_RESET` bigint(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MIN_COUNT_RESET` bigint(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVG_COUNT_RESET` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIME_ENABLED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIME_DISABLED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIME_ELAPSED` bigint(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIME_RESET` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TYPE` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COMMENT` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS` (
  `ID` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `FOR_COL_NAME` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `REF_COL_NAME` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `POS` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_FT_CONFIG
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_FT_CONFIG` (
  `KEY` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `VALUE` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS` (
  `POOL_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `POOL_SIZE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FREE_BUFFERS` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DATABASE_PAGES` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OLD_DATABASE_PAGES` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MODIFIED_DATABASE_PAGES` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PENDING_DECOMPRESS` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PENDING_READS` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PENDING_FLUSH_LRU` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PENDING_FLUSH_LIST` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGES_MADE_YOUNG` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGES_NOT_MADE_YOUNG` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGES_MADE_YOUNG_RATE` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGES_MADE_NOT_YOUNG_RATE` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NUMBER_PAGES_READ` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NUMBER_PAGES_CREATED` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NUMBER_PAGES_WRITTEN` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGES_READ_RATE` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGES_CREATE_RATE` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PAGES_WRITTEN_RATE` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NUMBER_PAGES_GET` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `HIT_RATE` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `YOUNG_MAKE_PER_THOUSAND_GETS` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NOT_YOUNG_MAKE_PER_THOUSAND_GETS` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NUMBER_PAGES_READ_AHEAD` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NUMBER_READ_AHEAD_EVICTED` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `READ_AHEAD_RATE` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `READ_AHEAD_EVICTED_RATE` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LRU_IO_TOTAL` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LRU_IO_CURRENT` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `UNCOMPRESS_TOTAL` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `UNCOMPRESS_CURRENT` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS` (
  `TABLE_ID` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `POS` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MTYPE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PRTYPE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LEN` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*************************** 1. row ***************************
INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN` (
  `ID` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `FOR_NAME` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `REF_NAME` varchar(193) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `N_COLS` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TYPE` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

If you want this metadata, you have two options

- OPTION #1: upgrade to MySQL 5.5 (for the 7 tables)
- OPTION #2: upgrade to MySQL 5.6 (for the 29 tables)